# Density of a point

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-distributions, density-function

*You choose a random point inside the triangle with vertices $A=(0,0),B=(1,3),C=(2,0)$*.
*Let $(X,Y)$ be the random double variable that indicates the point chosen.*
*Find the density of $(X,Y)$*

---

Ok, we have a an isosceles triangle inside the rectangle defined by variables $X\sim U(0,2)\Rightarrow f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{I}_{[0<x<2]}(x)$ and $Y\sim U(0,3)\Rightarrow f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{3}\mathbb{I}_{[0<y<3]}(y)$.

**Would somebody please explain me why the solution is:**

$$(X,Y) \sim U(T)$$

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{area(T)}=\dfrac13$$

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are dealing with uniform distribution on a triangle. That means that the PDF is constant on that triangle and takes value $0$ outside that triangle. Now use $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=1$ where $f$ denotes the PDF.

Comment: You fail to capture the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. For example, if $X = 1$, then we know that we must have $0\le Y \le 2$. Have you tried modelling this joint distribution?

Comment: No need for computational details beyond the computation of the area $3$. The explanation given by @drhab is then enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle is defined by $T = \left\{(x,y): y \in [0,3], \; |x -1| \leq 1-\dfrac{y}{3} \right\}$, and has area 3. So the pdf is $ f(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{3} \mathbf{1}_{(x,y) \in T}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain me why we have $|x-1|\leq 1-\frac{y}{3}$ in the domain?

Comment: @MarcoPittella That was a mistake. Corrected it now.

Comment: I corrected too. Despite this, I continue to not understand.

Comment: Notice that the triangle is symmetric about the line $x=1$, and that the "width" of the triangle varies from 2 at the bottom (where $y = 0$)to 0 at the top (where $y=3$).

Comment: Neither expression  $|x-1|<1-\tfrac13$ nor the fact that the width of the triangle varies from 2 to 0 are useful here ! Compute triangle area plainly as $\dfrac12$ base $\times$ height = $3.$

Comment: @JeanMarie The density is not $\dfrac{1}{3}$ over the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. The region needs to be specified.

Comment: I am fully conscious of that... I just said that for example having obtained $|x -1| \leq 1-\dfrac{y}{3}$ for the description of the triangle isn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to thank all those who answered. 
Ok, that's what I understood.

I draw the bisector to separate the triangle in two sections: one for $y<x$ and the other for $y>x$. Further, I use the mean of the triangle to separate the section where $x>1$ from the section $x<1$. Now I observe that:

- if $(y<x \cup x>1)\Rightarrow x-1<1-\frac{y}{3}$, in the sense that the length of the segment $x-1$ is, for each points of this area, smaller than the length of the segment $1-\frac{y}{3}$. By analogy,
- if $(y<x \cup x<1)\Rightarrow 1-x<1-\frac{y}{3}$.

It follows $|x-1|<1-\frac{y}{3}$, and like extremes of integration for $\int\int f(x,y)dxdy$ we have $0<y<3$ and $\frac{y}{3}<x<2-\frac{y}{3}$. Furthermore (***probably?***), we can apply the same reasoning in the area with $y>x$. However, I continue to not understand why:

1) this fact can help me to find the joint density $f(x,y)$

2) why $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{area(Triangle)}$, with $area(Triangle)=\frac{base\times heigth}{2}=\frac{2\times 3}{2}=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @drhab I also tried to calculate $1=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{\frac{y}{3}}^{2-\frac{y}{3}}f(x,y)dxdy$ treating $f(x,y)$ like a constant, but I obtained $f(x,y)=\frac{3-y}{2}$.

Comment: @drhab Correction: i calculated $1=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{\frac{y}{3}}^{2-\frac{y}{3}}f(x,y)dxdy$ and I obtain $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{3}$!